# Hibernate validation - Grouping for nested classes using @GroupSequence

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, hibernate-validator

I have such a **problem**: my validation grouping does not work correctly.
Here is my BookForm class:

```
@GroupSequence({BookForm.class, NameGroup.class, ReservationGroup.class})
public class BookForm {
    @NotEmpty(message = "Tenant first name should be filled out.", groups = NameGroup.class)
    private String tenantFirstName;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Tenant last name should be filled out.", groups = NameGroup.class)
    private String tenantLastName;

    @Valid
    @NotReserved(message = "Unfortunately, current apartment is already booked for these dates.", groups = ReservationGroup.class)
    private ReservationInfo reservationInfo;
    // getters and setters...
}
```

And here is ReservationInfo class:

```
@GroupSequence({ReservationInfo.class, DateCorrectnessGroup.class})
public class ReservationInfo {

    private long apartmentId;

    @Pattern(regexp = "^(0[1-9]|[12]\\d|3[01])\\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\\/([12]\\d{3})$",
        message = "Incorrect check in date. Please, try to book again.", groups = DateCorrectnessGroup.class)
    private String checkInDate;

    @Pattern(regexp = "^(0[1-9]|[12]\\d|3[01])\\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\\/([12]\\d{3})$",
        message = "Incorrect check out date. Please, try to book again.", groups = DateCorrectnessGroup.class)
    private String checkOutDate;
    // getters and setters...
}
```

I would like to validate my classes in such sequence:

1. Validate nested class fields (DateCorrectnessGroup)
2. Validate name fields (NameGroup)
3. Validate that current dates are not reserved (ReservationGroup)

**But** at the moment I get DateCorrectnessGroup validation errors together with NameGroup errors or ReservationGroup errors.

DateCorrectnessGroup, NameGroup, ReservationGroup are empty interfaces.

```
public interface DateCorrectnessGroup {}
public interface NameGroup {}
public interface ReservationGroup {}
```

Where is a problem?

Comment: Can you post the errors? Like, the stack trace?

Comment: There is no exceptions. The problem is an incorrect grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a new dummy annotation for cascading without applying `@NotReserved` on `reservationInfo`. Say the new annotation is `@FooBar` (Or, could we use `@NotNull`?)

```
@GroupSequence({DateCorrectnessGroup.class, NameGroup.class, ReservationGroup.class, BookForm.class})
public class BookForm {

    @NotEmpty(message = "...", groups = NameGroup.class)
    private String tenantFirstName;

    @NotEmpty(message = "...", groups = NameGroup.class)
    private String tenantLastName;

    @Valid
    @FooBar(groups = DateCorrectnessGroup.class)  // Could use @NotNull?
    @NotReserved(message = "...", groups = ReservationGroup.class)
    private ReservationInfo reservationInfo;

    // getters and setters...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not. The problem is still there... (1 error list) Incorrect check in date. Please, try to book again. + Tenant first name should be filled out. (2 error list) Incorrect check in date. Please, try to book again.
Unfortunately, current apartment is already booked for these dates.

Comment: @MZxFK Try removing  `ReservationInfo.class` in `@GroupSequence` from `ReservationInfo`.

Comment: @Minar_Mahmud w/o ReservationInfo.class: javax.validation.GroupDefinitionException: HV000054: container.dto.form.ReservationInfo must be part of the redefined default group sequence.